# How do I get my EC2 instance from EB to stop re-installing java 7?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, java-8, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

So, basically I have an EC2 instance that was created by Elastic Beanstalk and about every week I have been SSHing into it to uninstall java 7 and install java 8. The elastic beanstalk environment is set up for Node.js, but I have a separate java program that needs to be instantiated. I tried putting commands to install java 8 in rc.local but that didn't work at all. The file is now back to its default state. Is there somewhere where I can set up the instance to default to Java 8? Is there a way to just keep the installation that I install via SSH? Please help, my site keeps going down because of this and I'm not really sure what to do about it and google was not much help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.ebextensions is how I would do this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html

.ebextensions run anytime an ec2 instance is created; so script the uninstall of java 7 and install of java 8, and you're good to go.

More info...

It sounds like you understand that every now and again, EB automatically destroys your ec2 instance and replaces it. Often this is done on a weekly basis; take a look at the EB console -> Configuration -> Managed updates. You'll probably find that it says

`Managed updates: enabled`

`Weekly update window: [some date/time here]`

This is a good thing. EB is automatically installing important security and other updates for you. When it does this, it may replace your ec2 instances. Which means: the ec2 instance that you manually installed java 8 on is destroyed, and a brand new machine is created. This brand new machine has the default java 7 installed on it...and now you again have to SSH manually into this new instance and install 8.

What you need is a script that will run on all new ec2 instances that EB decides to create for you; this script will follow the steps you are taking each time you manually SSH into your ec2 instance. Note that even if you turned off managed updates, it's still possible (even likely) that ec2 instances get destroyed. This is a tenant of good infrastructure design; if an ec2 instance has a problem for any reason, your infrastructure should automatically in the background:

1.) Start a new ec2 instance

2.) Provision the new ec2 instance

3.) Reroute your website traffic to the new instance

4.) Decommission the old ec2 instance

So, in an .ebextensions file, create a script that will uninstall java 7 and install java 8 and you'll be all set.

Comment: This was very helpful! Thank you so much! Do you think a file like this would work out: 
`.ebextensions/java.config`:
``commands:
    java_8_install:
        command: "yum -y install java-1.8.0"
    java_7_uninstall: 
        command: "yum -y remove java-1.7.0-openjdk"``

Comment: @WilliamPapsco unfortunately I don't work with java, but yes it looks like you're on the right track. Whatever commands you use when you SSH in manually, do the same in the .config file (in the same order as well)